# Timezones are a few minutes difference - PHP - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am storing a timestamp into my database based on the `America/Chicago` timezone in PHP.  The problem is, whenever I return the time and compare it with `new Date()` in javascript, the `PHP` versioning of `Date` is 7 minutes behind.  They are both the same time zone `central time`.  Here is an example output from the server and the current:

`Sun Apr 10 2016 14:20:41 GMT-0500 (CDT) -> PHP
 Sun Apr 10 2016 14:27:53 GMT-0500 (CDT) -> JavaScript`

Suggestions?

Comment: javascript uses your local time I am pretty sure where PHP uses the server time.

Comment: So I should probably adjust the apache settings for my EC2 instance?

Comment: Well, if you look at the server time and then at the time of your PC, are them the same or 7 minutes apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to compare timestamps generated by your code, you need to ensure both timestamps are generated on the same machine.  So you either need to generate both on the client machine, or both on the server machine.  If you generate one on the client and one on the server, then they will not compare correctly if the clocks on the client and server have not been perfectly synchronized.

Comment: So strange, I am trying to change my `ubuntu` server time to `America/Chicago` but that outputs 7 minutes behind as well.